# Toggling Class Correctly

Tags: jquery, html, css, checkbox

I am trying to build a small website that displays failures. Here is a jsfiddle as an example: http://jsfiddle.net/hnQN7/2/

When you click a checkbox, it indicates a failure with that computer. In this example, computer A causes B, C, and D to fail - while the rest of the computers only fail on their own. Currently, I'm toggling classes to show failures. Unfortunately, this method has some issues. In particular, when I click checkbox A it displays that B, C and D have failed. But if I click checkbox B, while checkbox A is checked, it toggles B back to green. This isn't correct, as a failure with computer A should keep B red whether it's checked or not. At the same time, if A is not checked, B should only revert back to green if it's not checked.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Here is the script I currently have:

```
$('#computerA').click(function(){
    $('#computerA2').toggleClass('green failure');
    $('#computerB2').toggleClass('green failure');
    $('#computerC2').toggleClass('green failure');
    $('#computerD2').toggleClass('green failure');
})

$('#computerB').click(function(){
    $('#computerB2').toggleClass('green failure');

})

$('#computerC').click(function(){
    $('#computerC2').toggleClass('green failure');

})

$('#computerD').click(function(){
    $('#computerD2').toggleClass('green failure');
```

I apologize if this is a bit confusing. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I would prefer the best way to do is when you click on A all the other checkboxes should be disabled. its simple as that..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$('#computerA').click(function(){
    var state = this.checked;
    $('#computerA2, #computerB2, #computerC2, #computerD2').toggleClass('green', !state).toggleClass('failure', state);
})

$('#computerB, #computerC, #computerD').click(function(){
    var state = this.checked || $('#computerA').is(':checked');
    $(this).prev().toggleClass('green', !state).toggleClass('failure', state);
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zrYLh/)

Comment: This worked well, but now I've run into an additional issue. I've updated the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/zrYLh/3/. When I click on A and B, then uncheck B it displays that A and C are green - when C should still be a failure. If you have any suggestions on how to fix this issue, that would be great - thank you!

Comment: @user2155400 - why did you add more code to the fiddle Arun created? His doesn't exhibit the issue you're pointing to.

Comment: I wanted to be able to do the same thing he did and apply it to additional combinations of checks

Comment: @user2155400 - but the case you mentioned works fine with his answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#computerB').click(function(){
    !$('#computerA2').hasClass('failure') ? $('#computerB2').toggleClass('green failure') : '';
});
```

Check to see if computer A does not have the fail class, and if it doesn't, execute toggle, else do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just add this line in your click handlers for the other items:

```
          $('#computerB').click(function(){
              validateComputerA($('#computerB2'))
```

and add function to handle it all and then just call it and pass in your particular computer.

```
   function validateComputerA($comp){
      if(!$('#computerA2').hasClass('failure')){
         $comp.toggleClass('green failure');
       }
   }
```